# C, run n numbers of threads when 1 finish job create other thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to spawn N number of threads that execute a function I did that like this

```
for (int p = 0; p < threads; p++)
       pthread_create(&tid[p], NULL, dowork, full);
```

for now I used

```
for (int p = 0; p < threads; p++)
       pthread_join(tid[p], NULL);
```

to spawn again n number of threads, but I want to spawn another thread when one of the created threads finish.
For exemple I have 3 threads to do 6 jobs (running the same function 6 times with different parameters)
I create 3 threads if one of them finish create another thread immediately without waiting for all of them to finish.
How can I do that?

Comment: Why another thread instead of each thread just doing a bit more work and then terminating?

Comment: Like that is fine too, but I don't know when a specific thread finish

Comment: The problem with join is you'll know when they're *all* done, but if they finish out of order you have no way of knowing. Instead of complicating this code with message passing between threads and atomics/mutexes/locks, just do a bit more work in each thread and call it done.

Comment: Once a thread is done, `pthread_join` is unblocked. So you may add another thread to do the work. It's simple but you may not know which thread finished fastest. Just knowing joined thread is done.

Comment: I don't care which finished faster, I just want to know if from 3 threads 1 of them finished, but with unknown number of threads

Comment: Then you may create thread immediately after thread joined. Change check loop to while loop. Keeps the count of current running thread and task.

Comment: And how do I get the count of running threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a simple solution for fixed threads loops. It should be good enough if each task has similar operation time.

Take each line of comment as a snippet of code.

```
int finished_tasks = 0;
int threads = 3;
int todo_tasks = 6;
int check_index = 0;
// ...

// Create thread by variable `threads` ... 
for (int p = 0; p < threads; p++)
       pthread_create(&tid[p], NULL, dowork, full); 

while( finished_tasks < todo_tasks ){
    // Join one thread by check index;
    // finished_tasks++;
    // Check if finished tasks meets todo tasks, leave the while
    // Immediately create a new thread to do jobs
    // Move check index to next one.
}
```

Since one thread is done, and another thread is created immediately. The total thread counts are fixed to `threads`.

Pro

- Simple

Con

- Running thread is deviating from 1~ `threads`. Because while loop is always waiting for current thread join while other threads might finish faster than current thread.

This solution is good enough if each task has similar operation time. However if operation time deviation is too large, you need to make a synchronization for checking which thread is done first.